# MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrationsModelDiffer.HasDifferences()

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using MySql database with ASP.NET Core MVC application (version: .Net Core 3.1).
`startup.cs` class has auto-generated code:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(); // commenting this not showing exception page.
}
```

Here, if I remove the code: `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage()` it does not shows exception on running the program. I am not sure is needed for the program or not? Should I leave it commented? Or I should use it in code and solve the problem which might raising the exception.

On running the application - the page shows exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrationsModelDiffer.HasDifferences(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel)'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

I tried by checking:

- NuGet packages and they are all same version 5.0.17 (because that is the most recent supporting version for .NET 3.1)
- I have MySql connect / NET installed.
- I am not sure this is the cause of problem: I have this code in DbContext class (class is partial): `partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);`

Answer (score 0):

From [Database error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#database-error-page-3) we can see:

> Database Error Page Middleware captures database-related exceptions
> that can be resolved by using Entity Framework migrations.

You can use it in code and solve the problem which might raising the exception.

> NuGet packages and they are all same version 5.0.17

Because your ASP.NET Core MVC application (version: .Net Core 3.1), I suggest you make sure all of your EF packages were pointing at the same 3.1.X version.

Comment: Thank you so much Qing Guo. I downgrade all NuGet packages to 3.1.X and it solved the problem! Very helpful!